# How about having a community wiki with links to all Hindu scriptures available online?

Tags: discussion

As I was going through few questions, I found a couple of links to Hindu scriptures available online in the comments. I am unable to find those links now as I dont quite remember the original question.

This leads me to an idea of having a community wiki kind of thing on main site with all the links to available online texts like Vedas, Upanishads and Puranas.
This should definitely help users like me interested in reading these texts to answer questions on this site.

Any opinions?

Comment: @AwalGarg I am sorry but i did not find a comprehensive list of Hindu texts with links in that answer. close vote does not make sense to me

Comment: There are two answers there already, which we want to keep. Not that they completely answer either of the questions, but they are valid. If this remains open, we will have some answers here and some there which would not make sense. Thus I voted to close. If an answer comes here, we would rather have the questions merged. And I upvoted this question too since you took the time to raise a valid concern, so thanks for that.

Comment: ..and this citation post should be available when we type `hinduism.stackexchange.com/sources`.. something like this for quick reference (IMO).